# Reference a MovieClip symbol later on in the timeline 

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've been trying to reference a Library symbol that is introduced in Frame 2 by using it's instance name, using timeline scripting only.

I am trying to make a colour picker MC symbol for multiple re-use. Firstly I drew a small button on the stage and converted to MC, called `textColourPicker` of type `CPicker` (the class used to represent this MC in the Library). Inside this MC I have a button symbol called `pickerButton`

In the first frame of `textColourPicker` MC, I placed the code:

```
stop();
pickerButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doShowPicker);

function doShowPicker(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(2);

}
```

In Frame 2 of the `textColourPicker` instance, a new MC appears with instance name `pickerBox` of type `pickerBMP`. The `pickerBox` is then scale tweened until Frame 14 at which point I have the code:

```
stop();
pickerBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, cursorToColour);
```

Except I always get the error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at CPicker/frame14()[CPicker::frame14:10]
```

Here `CPicker` is referring to the Linkage name of the `textColourPicker` MC.

So `textColourPicker` is Instance of: `myPicker`, linkage name: `CPicker`

and `pickerBox` is instance of: `pickerBMP`, linkage name: `pickerBMP` (residing inside the `textColourPicker` MC.

Why is not allowing me to reference the `pickerBox` MC on Frame 14 of the `textColourPicker`?

This graphic of the `textColourPicker` timeline may help illustrate all this (note the two timeline scripting icons, first in Frame 1 last in Frame 14:

[image: Timeline screengrab]

Comment: in the 14th frame what is the the pickerBMP layer object name?

Comment: @Jevgenij Dmitrijev - it is the same name that it always is which is `pickerBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a post for InsideRIA about doing exactly what you are trying to do.  It is archived here:

http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html

It seems to me that your best bet is the getter/setter method, since you have a keyframe at the end where a new value will be inserted into the variable's value.

Example code for both methods is available here http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2010/04/sample-code-for-oop-timeline-insideria.html

HTH;

Amy

Comment: Hi Amy, thanks for the answer...! :) So what I'm doing is deciding if I should use the document class or a class file I am using separately from all this (in the main application). My main concern is re-usability; I guess I can import a .swf instead. Thanks again!

Comment: If you look at the example code, you will see that the way it works is that the main fla file uses the .as file as its document Class-- this can be reused by any fla file that has the same needs.

I am not sure how importing a swf file actually relates to any of this.  Can you explain what you were intending to do with the imported swf?

Comment: Simply to have a file that can always be used as a colour picker, without having to code in classes/events for every project that might use the picker.

Comment: Yes, you can use this technique with the Library symbol as well.  Instead of attaching the as file to the fla as the Document Class, attach it to the symbol in its as linkage.  It essentially means the same thing, that you want the Symbol to extend the as file (where using it as the Document class means that you want the whole swf to extend the as file).

Comment: Thanks Amy - so after a few hours spent figuring it out, it all boils down to the *root* of each mc being the best (and often the only) place to put code, i.e. in frame 1. In the end I created a custom event class and used dispatchEvent() from the timeline (but had to resort to using the doc root).