# in actionscript 3.0, when removing a child, why does the code still run?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm switching over from Actionscript 2.0 to Actionscript 3.0, and I'm missing a few key lines of code. Let's say I had a missile, and when it leaves the screen, in Actionscript 2, I would just use

```
removeMovieClip(this);
```

In Actionscript 3.0, I think I'm supposed to use

```
parent.removeChild(this);
```

Problem is, the code still runs. For example, I have a trace on frame 1, and then this code on Frame 30. Then when I run the program, it would run frame 1, then the object would "disappear", and then the trace happens again and when Frame 30 comes around again, I get TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

So what am I doing wrong? Am I not deleting/etc properly? I realize that there are a few questions similar to this but they don't seem to have the answers I'm looking for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this = null after you remove it but should be done from the parent so this.removeChild( child ); child = null;

Comment: You could also try adding an eventlistener for removeFromStage to do your clean up on that object and halt anything running in it. then of course null it out somehow. This is OOP after all and the object should take care of itself. Aside from the nulling which should be done from the parents view.

Comment: You might want to check the answer to a similar question I had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792291/reference-a-movieclip-symbol-later-on-in-the-timeline It's a problem of referencing an object that is not present in the 'root' (aka Frame 1 of any MC).

Answer (score 1):

Removing a display object from the display doesn't destroy the object. You'll need to destroy the object manually. Here's an illustration of adding and removing display objects:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(mc);
trace(mc); // traces [Object MovieClip]

removeChild(mc);
trace(mc); // traces [Object MovieClip]

mc = null;
trace(mc); // traces null
```

Keep in mind, setting an object to "null" doesn't necessarily destroy it. If you have event listeners or references to this object in your code, Flash will still hold it in memory. In this case you would want to create a "destroy" function for the object. This function would remove any reference to the object and remove any event listeners.

Comment: Correct statement (*Removing a display object from the display doesn't destroy the object.*), but incredibly awful illustration.

Comment: This is only somewhat right, nulling all references will not stop the code execution, only make it eligible for garbage collection, which will happen at some undetermined point in time. Code will still execute until the GC runs.

Comment: This was intended to be an incredibly simple illustration. The MovieClip object in this example doesn't have any code execution. As I mentioned in my answer, setting to null won't work in the case where you have code executing or references to the object.

Comment: In that case your response doesn't answer the original posters question. Definitely useful information though.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. In regards to null, an object can't set itself to null, right? as in "this = null;" . So the parent would have to make the child null, right?

Comment: Yeah. I realized that I misread the question after I posted. Sorry @Bao.

Comment: @bao you would want to still remove the child as Corey does in the code above, and it could set itself to null, but is only needed if it has a reference (it might not) parent.myObject = null;

Comment: Generally not a good idea to call parent methods from a child.

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript code will continue to execute until the object is cleaned up by the garbage collector. If you want it to stop, you must explicitly stop whatever is causing the code execution. On a movieclip that means calling `myMovieClip.stop()` if you are relying on an enterframe event, simply remove the listener.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I guess for now, I would 1) set the missile's x and y co-ordinates to -9999, 2) parent.removeChild(this), 3) stop() and removing the EnterFrame listeners. And later, if I want to re-add the child with the same name, it would work without any problems, right?

Comment: Correct, you can re add it later if you want. You would then want to call play() on it to start things up again. Changing the x/y is really a unneeded step, but I realize you may be doing that for other reasons.

Comment: @Bao Regarding your point 2) - In general I think you should let the class responsible for adding a child, to the display list, also be the one to remove it. That way it will be much easier to follow the flow of the code and to understand what's going on. You could do it by simply changing some kind of flag, say: `isDead` and then have the parent class look for it and appropriately remove it's child. This is especially important if the parent class holds listeners to the child class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure there are no event listeners attached to the movieclip. You also need to be sure that there is no reference (in any array or any other object) to the movieclip. You also need to say *mc = null* to remove the movieclip itself.

Otherwise FlashPlayer holds the clip in memory and it will exist forever, even when it is already removed from the displaylist.